# Loading Google Maps API via AJAX, console error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a fully dynamic website using jquery/javascript, ajax and php.

When I click on a navigation link, the browser opens that page using ajax.

So basically all pages are loaded within the same index.php.

If I go to 'Location' tab, where I have a google map, it will load the Google Maps script dynamically (adding a script tag to the body).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;callback=initialize"></script>
```

This script is loaded automatically by the previous script

```
<script src="https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/19/1/intl/hr_ALL/main.js"></script>
```

When I leave the 'Location' page, I check if the scripts are present and remove them.

If I go back to 'Location' without refreshing the page, I thought the map would have a clean start, but I get this error in console:

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors.

Even though the scripts were previously removed, and the map and content changed to something else, I get that error.

Since I know I have only once instance of the map, should I just ignore it?

Or it really has some kind of reference to the old map, and removing the two scripts is just not enough.

Thank you for any information!

Comment: Why don't you just link gmaps library once and for all during first page load ? It's better than reloading it each time you need it and I guess it solves your problem.

Comment: You mean I add the gmaps script to index.php and use initialize() on a certain page? 
EDIT:
Can this approach increase load time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Removing script-elements will not remove objects that have been created by these scripts( basically it will not have any effect).

Check if the maps-API already has been loaded:

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
if(!window.google||!window.google.maps){
  var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&' +
        'callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
else{
  initialize();
}});
</script>
```

Comment: This fixed the console error problem, and the scripts are loaded only once. But now when it re-initializes it does not show the map properly. Instead of full width it shows ~200px

Comment: The map-container obviously doesn't have it's final size when you call initialize ...impossible to provide a solution without knowing when he gets is final size(do you use some kind of animation?)

Comment: I erased my prior comments because I misunderstood your comment, and when I wanted to write a new one I hit enter before finishing... Never mind. Your last solution might fix the problem. I will post back soon. Thank you

Comment: how exactly do you load the pages, please show the related code(e.g. `getpage()`)

Comment: getPage() function gets the .php page via ajax `.load()`. When it's finished loading it animates the old page out, and new page in via `.animate()`. Now I use your code in the animation callback. Everything works great, except when I change the page and go back again, I get stacks of `<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?...</script>`, that appear to be only temporary (~20sec). Could this cause any problems?

Comment: I wouldn't care about it, usually the API loads the tiles from this address

Comment: Worked as expected