# Google map not showing in php page

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mozilla

I am implementing a google map in my webpage. On clicking a update button in index.php, I am showing a dialog box which contains google map for users to locate their location. Map is not showing properly. Please help me!

My js:

```
if(!window.google||!window.google.maps){
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&' +
    'callback=initialize';
document.body.appendChild(script);
}
else{
  initialize();
}


 <script>
    var directionsDisplay,
    directionsService,
    map;

    function initialize() {
         var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
        var mapOptions = { zoom:3, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, center: chicago }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), mapOptions);
        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
           position:chicago,
  });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}
```

HTML

```
<div name="mapdetail" value="" id="googlemap" style="width:350px;height:300px;"class="" >
```

The output:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you get map by clicking button first time? Which function you are calling by button?

Comment: did you loading this map in loop?

Comment: @Napster On clicking button the users are allowed to edit their information which includes their location.

Comment: @QaisarSatti I am not loading map inside loop

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216159/loading-google-maps-api-via-ajax-console-error/27216605#27216605

Comment: @Dr.Molle My map is not loading properly.What can be the reason

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thanks for your comment.I have solved the issue in console of repeated loading of google map.But my map is not showing properly

Comment: How did you solve the issue in the console?

Comment: @Dr.Molle I have checked whethergoogle map api is loaded in page using following keyword, window.google||!window.google.maps

Comment: @Dr.Molle I have edited the question and code

Comment: can you give a link/provide a demo?

Comment: @Dr.Molle if you have teamviewer9,I can give my details